# use a eikon fingerprint reader for full disk encryption

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption, fingerprint, manjaro

I have a eikon finger print reader and im wondering if anyone has any ideas of how i could use it to decrypt a Linux partition. I would ideally like it to work with my Manjaro installation (which is based on archlinux) to decrypt the drive and log in with a password or my fingerprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fingerprints are only usable for authentication, not encryption.

- For one, they're *public* – sometimes they could be easily lifted from the computer itself.
- For another, they don't have enough information to act as a secure encryption key.
- And the information they *do* have isn't fixed – the reader has to do a slightly fuzzy match since the print can change slightly over time.

Comment: And here I was wondering if the little scanners might actually be able to get a pro-level fingerprint scan - I take it they can't? But aren't they used for login authentication in Windows, can that be done in linux too?

Comment: @Xen2050: There is no "pro-level scan" that would give you sufficient unchanging details to generate a strong cryptographic key from a fingerprint...

Comment: @Xen2050: They're used for _authentication_ in Windows, where the OS already has the same fingerprint accessible on disk, and just compares it with what was read. That's not the same as encryption, where the key itself needs to be determined. So, sure, Linux can do fingerprint-based authentication with fprintd.

Comment: I was thinking of a LUKS-style strong key being decrypted with a short/poor passphrase...  but I take it the "fuzzy" reader wouldn't return even a reliable short passphrase (and probably require the fingerprint "image" file to be in plain sight on the drive too, not entering any real password before using it). Interesting

Comment: @Xen2050: Well, all widely-used FDE system will already use such an "encrypted key" (to avoid having to re-encrypt the whole disk whenever you change the password)... But, now that I think of it, _perhaps_ there are some fingerprint readers that could have their own tamperproof key storage and release a key after authenticating you?